# Wireless roaming mixing brands

Tags: wireless-networking

The WiFi provided by my ISP's router isn't good enough to transmit to the far side of my home (due to construction materials).

I bought an ubiquiti AP that I installed at the far side of my home (ethernet) with the same wireless SSID and password as my router.

I made sure that the channels are different.

It seems that when I am close to my router, my devices are still connected to the ubquiti's AP which is too far (according to the device, I have only 30% of reception).

Now, my question is: Can I mix two brands to have roaming wireless or should I plan to buy another ubiquiti AP ?

Thanks

Comment: That’s a common issue. To work around this client side problem, you can try and set your Ubiquiti AP to disconnect clients when reaching a set signal quality threshold. [See here](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/205144650-UniFi-Set-minimum-RSSI-for-clients).

Comment: Looks interesting. Then I'll need to buy another ubiquiti AP as my IPS' router doesn't such feature. Do you know if this work without having an "always on" controller?

Comment: It may be available with something like OpenWRT, if it’s available for your router.